# Spectrum of a product of operators on a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two operators on a Banach space X.
I am interested in the relationship between the spectra
of $A$, $B$ and $AB$.
In particular, are there any set theoretic inclusions
or everything can happen in general like:
$\sigma(A) \subset \sigma(AB)$, and conversely,
$\sigma(B) \subset \sigma(AB)$, and conversely?
If we know the spectra $\sigma(A)$, $\sigma(B)$ of
$A$ and $B$, can we determine the spectrum of $AB$?
I would appreciate any comment or reference.

Comment: similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19464/spectrum-of-the-sum-of-two-commuting-matrices/19465#19465

Comment: Even in one dimension, neither $\sigma(A) \subset \sigma(AB)$ nor $\sigma(B) \subset \sigma(AB)$ need hold.

Comment: Suppose I have $\sigma(AB)= \sigma(BA)$ for complex $2\times 2$ matrices. What more properties of $A$ and $B$ we can compare?

Answer (score 28):

If $A$ and $B$ commute, then $\sigma(AB)\subseteq \sigma(A)\sigma(B)$.  This can be seen by applying the Gelfand transform to the commutative Banach algebra consisting of all operators that commute with all operators that commute with $A$ and $B$.  (The reason to take the double commutant rather than simply the Banach algebra generated by $A$, $B$, and the identity is that the spectra of $A$, $B$, and $AB$ may be larger relative to the latter algebra.)

If $A$ and $B$ do not commute, things aren't as nice.  E.g., if $A$ is a nonzero nilpotent (or quasinilpotent) operator on a Hilbert space and $B=A^*$, then $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)=\{0\}$, but the spectral radius of $AB$ is $\|A\|^2\neq0$.  For a very concrete example consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

The spectra of $A$ and $B$ can also be much larger than that of $AB$, even in the commutative case.  The spectrum of an invertible operator $A$ can be an arbitrary compact subset of the complex plane not containing $0$, but $\sigma(AA^{-1})=\{1\}$.  For a noncommutative example, the spectrum of a nonunitary isometry $S$ on Hilbert space (like the unilateral shift) is the closed unit disk, while $\sigma(S^*S)=\{1\}$ and $\sigma(SS^*)=\{0,1\}$.

---

Here's a little more detail on the first paragraph. Let $a$ and $b$ be commuting elements of a unital Banach algebra $\mathcal{A}$ (for instance, $\mathcal{A}$ could be the algebra of all bounded operators on a Banach space).  In order to compare the spectrum of $ab$ to that of $a$ and $b$, we want to apply the Gelfand transform to a commutative Banach algebra $\mathcal{B}$ containing $a$ and $b$.  One must be careful, however, because if $a,b,1_\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$, there may be elements of $\mathcal{B}$ that are invertible in $\mathcal{A}$ but whose inverses lie in $\mathcal{A}\setminus\mathcal{B}$.  To ensure that this doesn't affect the spectra of $a$, $b$, or $ab$, one can either just stipulate that $\mathcal{B}$ also contains all elements of the form $(a-\lambda)^{-1}$, $(b-\lambda)^{-1}$, and $(ab-\lambda)^{-1}$, as $\lambda$ ranges over the resolvent sets of $a$, $b$, and $ab$ respectively, or just take the double commutant of $\{a,b\}$ in $\mathcal{A}$, which will automatically contain all of these elements.

Once the problem is reduced to the case of elements $a$ and $b$ of a commutative unital Banach algebra $\mathcal{B}$, the Gelfand transform gives you a homomorphism $\Gamma:\mathcal{B}\to C(X)$, where $C(X)$ is the (Banach) algebra of continuous complex-valued functions on the maximal ideal space of $\mathcal{B}$ with pointwise operations (and $\sup$ norm, but that isn't very important here).  One of the most fundamental properties of the Gelfand transform is that it preserves spectra; that is, for all $c\in\mathcal{B}$, $\sigma(c)=\Gamma(c)(X)$.  Using this fact, the inclusion $\sigma(ab)\subseteq\sigma(a)\sigma(b)$ is translated to a tautological fact about the range of a pointwise product of functions.

To prove that $\sigma(c)=\Gamma(c)(X)$, remember that $X$ can be identified with (or is defined to be, depending on your perspective) the set of nonzero homomorphisms from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.  If $\phi\in X$, then $\phi(c-\phi(c))=0$, which, since unital homomorphisms send invertible elements to invertible elements, shows that $c-\phi(c)$ is not invertible.  This shows that $\Gamma(c)(\phi)$ is in the spectrum of $c$, so $\Gamma(c)(X)\subseteq\sigma(c)$.  Conversely, if $\lambda\in\sigma(c)$, then there is a maximal ideal $M$ of $\mathcal{B}$ containing $c-\lambda$, and by the Mazur-Gelfand theorem there is a unique isomorphism $\mathcal{B}/M\cong \mathbb{C}$.  Composing with the quotient map gives a $\phi\in X$ with kernel $M$, so in particular $\phi(c-\lambda)=\phi(c)-\lambda = 0$, showing that $\lambda=\Gamma(c)(\phi)$, so that $\sigma(c)\subseteq\Gamma(c)(X)$.

To learn more about this, I recommend consulting any good textbook on functional analysis or Banach algebras.  For example, [Rudin](http://books.google.com/books?id=Sh_vAAAAMAAJ&q), [Douglas](http://books.google.com/books?id=-OdfXeNmrT0C&dq), and [Rickart](http://books.google.com/books?id=PVrvAAAAMAAJ&q) are good sources for the Gelfand theory that vary widely in emphasis and additional topics covered.  As for your question about whether $\sigma(T^{-1}ATB)\subseteq\sigma(A)\sigma(B)$ for commuting $A$ and $B$, the answer is that this need not hold if $T^{-1}AT$ and $B$ do not commute.  For example, let $A=B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $T=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Eric: You're welcome.

Comment: I couldn't imagine a better answer! Thank you very much Jonas!

Comment: Can you please give reference for $\sigma(AB)\subseteq \sigma(A)\sigma(B)$ for commuting operators, as I would like to see more details. Consider now again commuting $A$, $B$ and invertible $T$. Is it stll true that $\sigma(T^{-1}ATB)\subseteq \sigma(A)\sigma(B)$ ? That would be nice.

Comment: @Martin: I've added some details.

Comment: This has to be one of the best answers on this site. Every time I get a little tripped up on the spectrum of a product of operators, I invariably find myself here and sort things out based on what you wrote.