# How to prove $r(T_1 + T_2) \leq r(T_1) + r(T_2)$ when $T_1T_2 = T_2T_1$ for bounded linear operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are bounded linear operators in a complex banach space and $r(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$, satisfying
$$
r(A) = \inf_{n>0} \|A^n\|^{1/n} =  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|A^n\|^{1/n} = \sup_{x\in \sigma(A)} \|x\|,
$$
where $\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum of $A$. If $T_1T_2 = T_2T_1$, we want to prove that 
$$
r(T_1+T_2) \leq r(T_1) + r(T_2) \tag{*}.
$$

I was thinking maybe I can use
$$
(T_1+T_2)^n = \sum_{k=1}^n \begin{pmatrix}n \\ k\end{pmatrix}T_1^kT_2^{n-k}
$$
to get some useful results. But still I cannot figure out how to prove $(*)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with Banach algebras?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318028/on-the-spectrum-of-the-sum-of-two-commuting-elements-in-a-banach-algebra

Comment: @LuizCordeiro I am not familiar with Banach algebras, but I may have worked out a proof just now (posted below).

Comment: Are they required to be normal? No! So the natural setting will be unital Banach algebras. There the main tool is the Gelfand map. Try that!

Answer (score 1):

$\exists n_0$, s.t. $\|T_1^{n_0}\| \leq (r(T_1)+\epsilon )^{n_0}$ and $\|T_2^{n_0}\| \leq (r(T_2)+\epsilon )^{n_0}$.
$$
\begin{split}
\|(T_1+T_2)^n\| 
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \begin{pmatrix}n \\ k \end{pmatrix} \|T_1^k T_2^{n-k}\|\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \begin{pmatrix}n \\ k \end{pmatrix} \|T_1^{n_0}\|^{\lfloor k/n_0 \rfloor} \|T_1\|^{r_k} \|T_2^{n_0}\|^{\lfloor (n-k)/n_0 \rfloor} \|T_2\|^{r_{n-k}}  \\
&\leq \frac{\|T_1\|^{n_0}\|T_2\|^{n_0}}{\|T_1^{n_0}\|\|T_2^{n_0}\|}\sum_{k=1}^n \begin{pmatrix}n \\ k \end{pmatrix} \|T_1^{n_0}\|^{k/n_0}\|T_2^{n_0}\|^{(n-k)/n_0}  \\
& = Const \cdot (\|T_1^{n_0}\|^{1/{n_0}} + \|T_2^{n_0}\|^{1/{n_0}})^{n}
\end{split}
$$
Let $n\rightarrow \infty$, we have 
$$
r(T_1+T_2) \leq r(T_1) + r(T_2) + 2\epsilon.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You need a small variation of your idea. First, we may assume without loss of generality that $\|T_1\|\leq1$, $\|T_2\|\leq1$. Now you take $n_0$ such that $\|T_1^{n}\| \leq (r(T_1)+\epsilon )^{n}$ and $\|T_2^n\|\leq(r(T_2)+\epsilon)^n$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Also, since $\|T_1^k\|^{1/k}\to r(T_1)$ and $\|T_2^k\|^{1/k}\to r(T_2)$, there exist $c_1,c_2>0$ with 
$$
\|T_1^k\|^{1/k}\leq c_1,\ \ \ \ \|T_2^k\|^{1/k}\leq c_2\ \ \ \text{ for all } k.
$$

Now, for $n\geq 2n_0$, let $d_j=r(T_j)+\epsilon$ and $$R=1+\max\left\{ \left(\frac{c_1}{d_1}\right)^k+\left(\frac{c_2}{d_2}\right)^{n-k}:\ k=0,1,\ldots,n_0\right\}. $$ The key fact is that $R$ does not depend on $n$. So
\begin{align}
\|(T_1+T_2)^n\| 
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose  k} \|T_1^k\|\,\| T_2^{n-k}\|\\ \ \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n_0-1} {n\choose k}c_1^k\,d_2^{n-k}+\sum_{k=n_0}^{n-n_0}{n\choose k}d_1^k\,d_2^{n-k}+\sum_{k=n-n_0+1}^n{n\choose k}d_1^k\,c_2^{n-k}\\ \ \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n_0-1} {n\choose k}d_1^k\,d_2^{n-k}\,\left(\frac{c_1}{d_1}\right)^k+\sum_{k=n_0}^{n-n_0}{n\choose k}d_1^k\,d_2^{n-k}+\sum_{k=n-n_0+1}^n{n\choose k}d_1^k\,d_2^{n-k}\,\left(\frac{c_2}{d_2}\right)^{n-k}\\ \ \\
&\leq R\,\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\,d_1^kd_2^{n-k}
=R\,(d_1+d_2)^n.
\end{align}
Then
$$
r(T_1+T_2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|(T_1+T_2)^n\|^{1/n}=(d_1+d_2)\,\lim_{n\to\infty}R^{1/n}=d_1+d_2=r(T_1)+r(T_2)+2\epsilon.
$$
As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we get $$r(T_1+T_2)\leq r(T_1)+r(T_2).$$