# Gelfand transform relation between the spectrum of $ab$ and the spectra of $a$ and $b$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

I want to have a better understanding of the Gelfand transform. This is a follow up regarding Julien's reply to the question [on the spectrum of the sum of two commuting elements in a Banach algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318028/on-the-spectrum-of-the-sum-of-two-commuting-elements-in-a-banach-algebra.):

> Assume that $A$ is commutative. Then by Gelfand, for every $x\in A$, we have
> $$
> \sigma(x)=\{\phi(x)\;;\;\phi\in \hat{A}\}
> $$
> where $\hat{A}$ denotes the set of characters (nonzero algebra homomorphisms from $A$ to $\mathbb{C}$).
>
> It follows readily that for all $x,y\in A$:
> $$
> \sigma(x+y)\subseteq\sigma(x)+\sigma(y)\qquad \mbox{and}\qquad\sigma(xy)\subseteq\sigma(x)\sigma(y).
> $$

My question is, why is clear from the above that we have

$$\sigma(x+y)\subseteq\sigma(x)+\sigma(y)\qquad  \text{and} \qquad\sigma(xy)\subseteq\sigma(x)\sigma(y)?$$

I understand that $\phi$ are homomorphisms, but where do the spectrums take place in the definition and how did we get "$\subseteq$"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda\in \sigma (x+y)$,  then there is some $\varphi $ in $\hat A$, such that $\lambda =\varphi (x+y)$.  Therefore
$$
  \lambda =\varphi (x+y) = \varphi (x)+\varphi (y)\in  \sigma (x)+\sigma (y).
  $$
Similarly for $xy$.