# Positive elements in star algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^\ast$-algebra. Is it possible to prove that if $a \ge 0$ then

$ab, ba \ge 0$ if and only if $b \ge 0$?

Comment: Here are a couple of posts that are relevant for similar spectral theory questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874324/on-the-spectrum-of-a-product-in-a-banach-algebra-in-specific-case and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19576/spectrum-of-a-product-of-operators-on-a-banach-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to prove that this is the case.

**(non-zero) Counterexample in $\Bbb C^{2 \times 2}$:**
$$
a = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad b = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}
$$

---

**Counterexample to the comment:**
$$
a = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad b = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$
note that neither $ab$ nor $ba$ is self adjoint. Note that $ab$ will be self-adjoint iff $a$ and $b$ commute.

Comment: What about only the direction $b \ge 0$ then $ab=0$?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean here.  In any case, notice that for this example $ab = ba = a \neq 0$.

Comment: I made a typo, I meant $b \ge 0$ then $ab,ba \ge 0$.

Comment: This is certainly not true.  Note that $ab,ba$ need not be self-adjoint.  Should we add that as an assumption?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, we could add self-adjoint as an assumption.

Comment: It is indeed true (for matrices, not sure about the general case) that if $a,b$ commute with $a,b\geq 0$, then $ab \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest counterexample: $a=0$.

Somewhat less trivial: in $C([0,1])$ let $a$ be a function that is $0$ on $[0,1/2]$ and nonnegative.  Then $ab = ba \ge 0$ if $b \ge 0$ on $[1/2, 1]$, but you could have $b(t) < 0$ somewhere in $[0,1/2)$.