# If $B$ is nilpotent and $AB=BA$ then $\det(A+B)=\det(A)$ (Asking for other method)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

> Let $K$ be some field and $A, B \in M_n(K)$. Prove that: If $B$ is nilpotent and $AB=BA$ then $\det(A+B)=\det(A)$.

I believe there is a nice solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159363/if-b-is-nilpotent-and-ab-ba-then-detab-deta). However, it seems that this problem could be solved using Jordan Canonical Form of the matrices. I am wondering how. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Didn't darij grinberg's hint under the linked question solve the problem?

Comment: I don't think you want JNF, but simultaneously triangularization.  Note that it is not true that $A,B$ can be simultaneously put into JNF.

Comment: I think the linked question has many good references. It is perhaps a bit misleading that the answers speaks about avoiding the "machinery of JNF". I also think, simultansous triangularization is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I only know simultaneous triangularization on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, does it work still on any general field?

Comment: Oh I found that any algebraically closed field works! Thanks!